# "AVPlayerStatusUnknown" always getting when network is slow on Http-LIVE Audio Streaming

Tags: objective-c, avplayer, http-live-streaming, avplayeritem

**Avplayerstatusunknown**
status always getting when network is slow and when i switched the strongest network sometime it is resume but for sometime it is again give response status "AVPlayerstatusunknown" till i will manually switch to another song.Any suggession why i am getting this status most of the time(When network slow)or how to avoid long term buffering in this case,Please help me